# Reading a file does not show changes that were just written

Tags: c++, fstream

I am new to c++. I made the following program which runs successfully and does its intended job which is to append the data of one file to another file.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<stdio.h>

using namespace std;

void show(const char *file)
{
  char data[90];
  fstream f(file,ios::in);
  while(!f.eof())
  {
    f.getline(data,90,'\n');
    puts(data);
  }
}
int main()
{
  char data[90];
  cout<<"Contents of files before data integration.\nFile 1:\n";
  show("file1.txt");
  cout<<"\nFile 2\n";
  show("file2.txt");
  fstream f1("file1.txt",ios::out|ios::app);
  fstream f2("file2.txt",ios::in);
  while(!f2.eof())
  {
    f2.getline(data,90,'\n');
    f1<<data<<'\n';
  }
 cout<<"\n\nFile 1 after data integration: \n\n";
 show("file1.txt");
}
```

As i checked separately the file appends the data in file1 successfully but the program prints only its old contents. Can anyone tell me what could be the possible reason for that and the remedy for the same.

Comment: Please explain how it "does it's intended job" if the "program prints only its old contents", I mean **what** are you asking?

Comment: Also how is this related to to being a "newbie on Linux", or even to Linux at all?

Comment: I have mentioned that it appends the contents in file1 as i checked seperately!

Comment: Please compile with `g++ -Wall -g` and learn how to use the `gdb` debugger.

Comment: I think Ed might have have intuited your underlying issue out, but I would also urge you to use `std::endl` instead of `\n`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Until the stream `f1` is closed, the contents that have been written to it may reside in a buffer.  If this happens, the last call to `show` will display the old contents of the file or (maybe worse) an incomplete version of the new contents.

Flushing could do the trick, as Ed Heal suggests in his answer, but I think that the proper way to do this is to close stream `f1` as soon as the writing finishes.  (Same for `f2`, if you like.)  Add the following lines just after the `while` loop and before the last call to `show`:

```
f1.close();
f2.close();
```

Answer (score 2):

If is buffering it.

Flush the stream and the smell of the old file goes away.

See http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ostream/ostream/flush/